# using shell_exec to open video file causes max execution time fatal error

Tags: php, xampp, vlc, execution-time

I'm running xampp on Windows 10, writing a personal media browser in a web browser environment from localhost. I'm using `shell_exec()` to open up VLC Media Player and start playing a given video file.

At first I executed the vlc command directly in shell_exec(), like:

`shell_exec('vlc -f "path/to/file.mp4"');`

It works as it should, opens up VLC (as if from the web browser), autoplays the video file, in fullscreen.

The problem is, it keeps running the script as long as VLC is open.

To try to get around this, I thought I'd do it via creating a batch file.

So now, on click of a file in the browser, I run ajax to the server and write a temporary `runvlc.bat` file to the current script directory, then use `shell_exec` to execute the batch file and auto-close the command prompt. I had thought that this would solve the running-script-as-long-as-VLC-is-open problem because `shell_exec` is only opening the batch file which exits itself.

However, that did not solve the problem. After 30 seconds, I still get the fatal error (maximum execution time) response from the server. It doesn't really hurt anything, but I'd like to solve this.

I remember reading somewhere that there's a way to pass the execution off so that php can continue, but I can't find that again.

This is what the code currently looks like on the server side:

```
private function test()
{
    $dir = getcwd();
    $batch = 'runvlc.bat';
    $handle = fopen($batch, 'w');
    $media = "file:///C:/mymovie.mp4";
    $data = 
"CD
CD C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC
start vlc -f --volume 75 \"$media\"
exit";
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    fclose($handle);
    $line = '"'.$dir.'\'.$batch.'"';
    shell_exec($line);
    return $this->response(array('status'=>'success')); 
}
```

Any ideas how to dissociate the execution from VLC's status as open/running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run your bat file with this function:

This will execute $cmd in the background (no cmd window) without PHP waiting for it to finish

```
public function bgExec($cmd) { 
        pclose(popen($cmd, "r"));  
} 

private function test()
{
    $dir = getcwd();
    $batch = 'runvlc.bat';
    $handle = fopen($batch, 'w');
    $media = "file:///C:/mymovie.mp4";
    $data = 
"CD
CD C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC

start vlc -f --volume 75 \"$media\"
exit";
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    fclose($handle);
    $line = '"'.$dir.'\'.$batch.'"';
    $this->bgExec($line);
    return $this->response(array('status'=>'success')); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made those adjustments. Now the response is instant but VLC doesn't open. I had tried it earlier with `start /B` in the `shell_exec` command but the batch file didn't run until I removed `start /B`.

Comment: But I just removed `start /B` from your `bgExec` function, and it works perfectly. Response is instant, and VLC opens immediately. No fatal error. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, that was really wrong... Nice it's working! Enjoy... @Thom

Comment: Thanks again. Big ups!